# Correct names for lycanthrope species with abnormally named base creatures

Tags: names, compounds

It's normally easy to name a lycanthrope species: just place "were" in front of the name of the base creature, i.e. "werewolf", "werebear", or "weredragon".

Sometimes, though, the base creature's name is an open compound word, i.e. the komodo dragon. The "komodo" part of the name is crucial to the identity of the creature; komodo dragons are not remotely regular dragons. Is the lycanthrope form a "werekomodo dragon"? The sounds like a dragon species with "werekomodo" as a qualifier. Someone once suggested "komodo weredragon", but that doesn't sound right to me, either. That sounds more like a dragon-based lycanthrope (which it is not), with "komodo" as some sort of qualifier. The final option I suppose would be "werekomododragon", which I favor most, but I still don't feel right about it.

How about the Mongolian death worm? This one not only has spaces in its name, but "Mongolian" is capitalized. Does the lycanthrope form end up being a "wereMongoliandeathworm"?

Comment: I'm not sure you can really call it "the lycanthrope form". The *were-* prefix actually means "man" (wer = vir as in virile). And so far as Google Books is concerned, even "weredragon" didn't exist until 1990, so there's no real precedent for using it on double- or triple-barrelled base forms. To maximise legibility, given your fantasy animal will probably be completely unknown to the average reader, I'd go for **"were-komodo-dragon"** (*with* the quote marks, alerting the reader to the fact that you're being "creative" with your written forms).

Comment: And remember that George Martin uses *weirwood* for his “man-trees” in *A Song of Ice and Fire* saga.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The "were" always prefixes a noun and does not prefix an adjective. Also, I don't think taking a group of words and gluing them together would be proper nomenclature.

So I would definitely go with

- Komodo weredragon
- Mongolian death wereworm

and my personal favourite:

- Three-toed weresloth

Comment: I think _wereworm_ all by itself has just become one of my favorite words. Imagine the Gothic horror tales -- and it sounds just right.

Comment: 'I don't think taking a group of words and gluing them together would be proper nomenclature.' So where is your justification for 'weresloth'?

Answer (score 2):

*Lycanthrope* has a respectable history in English, but it absolutely is not the 'general form of *werewolf*'; it is a synonym, from Greek *lycos* wolf and *anthropos* man. Enough people in Europe actually believed in the possibility of shapeshifting into wolves to need a special word for the concept, but nobody even considered the possibility of turning into any other animal; Saki made fun of the concept [here](http://www.eastoftheweb.com/cgi-bin/version_printable.pl?story_id=Gues.shtml).

With the growth of fantasy games and fiction (also known as the Death of Western Civilisation), you can of course use any word you please for a concept you invent; but you can't expect general acceptance of *werebear* or *weredragon* (at least until the first specimen appears on the evening news ravaging Tokyo) let alone the correct form of *Mongolian weredeath worm*.

Answer (score 0):

No one probably cares now, but I came across this and decided to answer it.

The Komodo Dragon is named as such because it lives on Komodo Island. So its name is literally, the Dragon that lives on Komodo Island. They Originated on Komodo Island and Indonesia is the only place in the world where these lizards live, so it doesn't need another name since you only find them on Komodo Island and neighboring Islands, in the wild.

It's a monitor lizard by scientific classification (Varanus komodoensis) and is a member of the monitor lizard family Varanidae.

So perhaps weredragon of Komodo is more appropriate? Or even werevaranus komodoensis?